# Ng Select is not showing, Cannot read Properties of null

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I am working with Angular 11 and I have installed ng select module version 6 since the latest one did not work with my current Angular version for this project, and according to their table this is the best fitting version for Angular 11.

The problem I am facing is that even after doing the right imports with no errors on app.module nor on the component I am working on, the console throws this error claiming there is a null property:

[image]

I am just testing with the default example given on their [github page](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) but still, no success. Although, I have tried following the same steps on another project (running Angular 15 with the latest version of ng select) and it worked just well.

Here is the the HTML code:

```
<ng-select [items]="cars" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id" [(ngModel)]="selectedCar">
</ng-select>
```

The .ts of this component:

```
  selectedCar: number;

  cars = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Volvo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Saab' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Opel' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Audi' },
  ];
```

The imports:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

I've also imported the style file on my styles.scss (the global style file for the project):

```
@import '~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css';
```

I would appreciate any help to understand the cause of this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to replace [(ngModel)] with [value]. The [(ngModel)] has been depricated. And probably your versions will work fine with [value] parameter

Comment: @dbonev the error now is gone, but curiously the select input does not appear. The same happened when I tried on the other project but I could fix it only by importing the styles file. Although, this one has the import but still I can not see the input...

Comment: Ok then back the ngModel and place the value inside the ng-select options like their documentation shows: <ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCar">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.id">{{car.name}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>

Comment: The error also shows up if i do that.

Comment: Npm install / are all the packages correct / delete package-lock.json and node_modules and reinstall them

Comment: Sadly this mothod did not work either..